# How can I switch debug mode on for some requests but not others with Django?

Tags: django

I want to be able to turn on Django's debug mode in production for users that are signed in with an account that belongs to my company. I initially assumed I could do this by manipulating the settings at runtime, but the [article on that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime) pointed out my error. What is the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: Shouldn't doesn't mean can't. Why would you want to enable it just for those users anyway? Maybe there's another solution to your root problem.

Comment: Indeed, but it also means that since the code assumes that the setting is never changed, changing it may not always update the right code paths. It also certainly means that it's unsupported.